# Blaze Persistence Graphql Query querying non selected fields

Tags: spring-data, blaze-persistence

I have an entity view for a blog article like so:

```java
public interface BlogArticleView {
    @IdMapping
    UUID getId();
    String getTitle();
    String getSlug();
    String getDescription();
    String getContent();
    Integer getLikes();
    Timestamp getCreatedDate();
    Timestamp getLastModifiedDate();
    List<BlogTagView> getTags();
    List<BlogCommentView> getComments();
}
```

Whenever I use graphql to query just the `description` field from an article (by looking up its ID), the following query is generated:

```sql
select b1_0.id,null,null,null,null,b1_0.created_date,b1_0.description,null,null,null,null,null from blog_article b1_0 where b1_0.id=?
```

For some reason, even though I specify just the description field, it also queries the created_date from the database. The same thing happens when I query for the title, and it also returns the `likes` attribute with it. How do I prevent this overfetching?

Comment: Are you sorting or filtering by these attributes?

Comment: Nope, I'm filtering by slug

Comment: I created https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/issues/1767 for tracking this. You can watch it if you want to receive updates about the problem. Ideally, you'd try to provide a reproducer for this problem based on the archetype: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#quickstart

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to get an example running as soon as possible!